# How to find an arbitrary key within a postgres jsonb object?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

There are several operators in postgres for getting elements at a certain path in jsonb.

But how could I retrieve all the values that have a key of 'foo', if I don't know where in the whole object structure they will appear?

I saw there is a regex matches function which would return me matching regexes, but the object keyed off foo could be arbitrarily complex, so tough to come up with a regex that would pull the whole object out neatly?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT jsonb_column->'foo'
FROM table
[WHERE jsonb_column ? 'foo'] -- ignore values without key "foo"
```